# Crear grupo mediante parametro en cmd

Tags: script, batch

Mediante el primer parámetro debo crear un grupo, a través de un script en código batch.

Tengo esto programado, pero al ejecutarlo me sale un error en la parte del else:

```
:: Comprobar que hay 3 parametros

set numparam=0
for %%a in (%*) do (

set /a numparam+=1
)

if %numparam% NEQ 3 (

echo el numero de parametros no es correcto, debe haber 3 parametros >&2
exit /b 1 

)  

::Comprobar que existe el parametro 1 y crear grupo

if exist %1 (


    :: para añadir el grupo local
    net localgroup %1 /add 


) else (


    echo el parametro 1 no es correcto, introduzca el nombre de un grupo >&2
    exit /b 1

)
```

En cmd:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿De qué modo podría solucionarlo? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que veo es que escribiste `numparam+`en lugar de `numparam` en la línea 6 de tu código

Podrías poner en su lugar :

```
set /a numparam=%numparam% + 1
```

Si lo corriges, podrías solucionar tu problema.

Si no funciona avísame para darte otra respuesta

Comment: Ese no es el problema. Es un operador soportado por [`set`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1).

Comment: No intento molestarte. ¡Bienvenido! Solo quiero ayudarte a que tus preguntas y respuestas sean bien recibidas. Antes que nada, investiga bien si no estás seguro a la hora de responder. También haz el [tour] y visita [ask] y [answer].

Comment: Ya hice todo eso, lo que pasa es que vas siguiendo todas mis acciones como si anduviera repartiendo información falsa, claro, yo entiendo que tienes que monitorear el sitio, pero tampoco me andes corrigiendo en todo.

Comment: que la pases muy bien

Comment: ya hice una nueva corrección más fácil de entender